# mpv: how to play a list of URLs piped from stdin

Tags: pipe, mpv

Is there a way to get mpv to play a list of URLs that are piped from another command's stdout?

My use case is to play all media links from an HTML page, e.g. with something like this:

```
extractlinks.py http://example.com '*.mp3' | mpv
```

`extractlinks.py` returns a list of playable URLs which could normally be considered a valid m3u playlist. I tried using `mpv --playlist` but it's not accepting the playlist from stdin.

Is there a way to get `mpv` to read a list of URLs from stdin?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The --playlist option allows you to specify a playlist from stdin if you use `-` as path,
Example:

```
ls | mpv --playlist=-
```

Comment: btw, for the specific case you list in your example, ie, playing all files in a local folder, you can simply use `mpv .` — this will additionally traverse all the subfolders recursively.

Answer (score 0):

As @ccpizza points out in the comment above. You can use `mpv .` to play all the file inside directory and subdirectory.

To exclude some file, use `$ mpv !(*.jpg|*.png)`. Remember you need to activate your `extglob` beforehand, `shopt -s extglob`.